# Find out a file name when you are in presentation mode JetBrains

Tags: file, ide, webstorm, filenames, jetbrains-ide

How can I find out a file name when I am in presentation mode in JetBrains ide?

Namely I am using Webstorm and I do not see a way to determine a file name for the file I am viewing.

For example here, there is no name:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Try the Jump to Navigation Bar action (Cmd-Up/Alt-Home) - it shows the file name and its location on the project.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara, oh. Great. You should definitely post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-120266](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120266) and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with this feature